# mandrill ajax call is returning an error when attempting to send email

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, mandrill

When i attempt to click the button on my page, the expected result which is to send an email does not seem to work.

I do see `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL` in the console and the line the console error points to is the first property of the ajax method which is the post.

```
  btnSendEmail.click(function(){
    var fromEmail = txtEmail.val();
    var senderName = txtName.val();
    var toEmail = "someemail@floormind.com";
    var mandrillKey = "SOME API KEY";
    var emailContent = txtEnquiry.val();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: “https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send.json”,
      data: {
        ‘key’: mandrillKey,
        ‘message’: {
          ‘from_email’: fromEmail,
          ‘to’: [
              {
                ‘email’: toEmail,
                ‘name’: senderName,
                ‘type’: ‘to’
              }
            ],
          ‘autotext’: ‘true’,
          ‘subject’: ‘Enquiry’,
          ‘html’: ‘YOUR EMAIL CONTENT HERE! YOU CAN USE HTML!’
        }
      }
    }).done(function(response) {
      $('#modalSendEmail').modal('hide');
      console.log(response); // if you're into that sorta thing
    });
  });
```

Comment: `‘` is not legal Javascript.

Comment: Neither is `“`. Use `'` and `"`.

Comment: Thanks... that solves the issue @JasonP